# VS Code Intellisense for node type require()

Tags: intellisense, visual-studio-code

Using VS Code - still in my first day. I was really hoping IntelliSense was going to be straight forward after watching all the MS videos about its support for Node.js, but no luck for me. So:

Given File1:

```
function generateCanvas(FileOrURL){
    ...
}

module.exports.generateCanvas = generateCanvas;
```

And File2:

```
var cFX = require('./scripts/classes/CanvasFX.js');
cFX.
```

Should I be getting Intellisense for 'generateCanvas' after `cFX.`? It's kind of driving me nuts. ANY help would be appreciated.

I've tried (the only thing I can think of):

`module.exports = generateCanvas`

`module.exports = function generateCanvas(...) {...}`

jsconfig:

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    },
"exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components",
    "jspm_packages",
    "tmp",
    "temp"
]
```

Comment: Did you try creating a .jsconfig.json file in the root directory of the project? https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/javascript#_javascript-projects-jsconfigjson

Comment: Issue confirmed [#4943](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/4943)

Comment: plus related [#7831](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7831)

Comment: These issues seem to be fixed, as of Apr 10, '16.